# Bootstrap Dropdown: How to set active link to display value on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I created a dropdown list that will be used to choose the number of images to display on one page. I would like to set a default and show that default value on the button itself instead of a label. I already know how to do this when a a selection if made, but not for a default value

```js
$('.dropdown1 button').click(function(){
    $('#show').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group1 mr-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="show"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown1">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">24</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">16</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">32</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gerard, I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me with your edit. The code is the same but you added script tags. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: He turned your code into a Stack Snippet, so that people can run it versus just looking at it...

Comment: More on [Stack Snippets can be found here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @JeffS As Matt suggested. But when running the snippet an error occurred so I rolled it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `id` to set the desired default selected value, then use the `$(document).ready(...)` event to set the default value via `jQuery`.

---

*On the 'option' that you want to be the default:*

```
<button id="default-option" class="dropdown-item" type="button">24</button>
```

*`jQuery` Snippet:*

```
$('#show').text($(".dropdown1 button[id='default-option']").text());
```

---

***Something like this:***

```js
$('.dropdown1 button').on('click', function(){
    $('#show').text($(this).text());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').text($(".dropdown1 button[id='default-option']").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group1 mr-4">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="show"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown1">
    <button id="default-option" class="dropdown-item" type="button">24</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">16</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">32</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it. Set an id="default" and set $('#show).text() to $('#default).text().
Seems to work.

```js
$('#show').text($('#default').text());
$('.dropdown1 button').click(function(){
    $('#show').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group1 mr-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="show"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown1">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="default">24</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">16</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">32</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">All</button>
    </div>
</div>

  
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```